# How to align two items in a same row properly

Tags: react-native, flexbox, alignment

I have a `View` which contains an `Icon` and another `View`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: row}}>
    <Icon name={'dot} style={{marginRight: 16}} />
    <View>
       {Children}
    <View>
</View>
```

And this is how output renders

[image]

It is apparent that `dot` and `child View` are not aligned properly. I want this alignment to be like this

[image]

I have changed `Icon's` `style` to achieve this,

```
<Icons name={'dot'} style={{marginRight: 16, marginTop: 6}} />
```

Here, Things I am not clear about are,

1.Why `Icon` is rendering at a bit higher position than `View`?
2. applying `marginTop` seems like a hack around. so, Is there any style element or prop to make them aligned properly without using `margintop`

**Result Of Avinash Nayak's answer:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your children props has some padding or margin top.

or you can  try bellow hack.

```
<View style={{
     flexDirection: row,
    }}>
        <Icon name={'dot} style={{marginRight: 16}} />
        <View style={{marginTop:-4}}> // adjust the value 
           {Children}
        <View>
    </View>
```

Comment: Pleas have a look t my updated question after applying your styling. It is center aligned now. But i want alignment as I shown in the second pick

Answer (score 0):

1. Why Icon is rendering at a bit higher position than View?

   The view elements are rendering correctly inside the parent view, how ever, while you align `Text` and `Icon` that looking a bit weird but it is the correct way. Try to check the starting `y coordinate` of `Text` and `Icon` by keeping background color to both of them. You will come to know that both starting from the same position from top.
2. Applying `marginTop` seems like a hack around. so, is there any style
   element or prop to make them aligned properly without using
   `marginTop`?

   I guess **NO**, this is the only way, either you can add `marginTop` or `top` styles to adjust the top position.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below code Changes:

```
<View style={
    {
       flexDirection: "row",
    }
}>
    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }} >
        <Icon name={'dot'} style={{marginRight: 16}} />
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
        {children}
    </View>
</View>
```